# Facebook canvas GET param (app_data)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, canvas, request, facebook-apps

I am trying to get app_data from the facebook canvas.

It's working in page tab.

```
https://www.facebook.com/something/app_55218516481307?app_data=4B9E753

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$app_data = $signed_request["app_data"];
```

app_data contains the value - '4B9E753' So, it's nice.

But there, app_data is not even set.

```
https://apps.facebook.com/namespace/?app_data=something
```

signed_request contains only

```
Array ( 
    [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
    [issued_at] => 65456446
    [user] => Array ( 
        [country] => cz
        [locale] => cs_CZ
        [age] => Array ( 
        [min] => 21 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only works in a page tab and not on the canvas page.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/
to send data to the app on its canvas app page use 
'https://apps.facebook.com/yourappname?sk=app_yourapp_id/whatever_you_wish_to_send/'
and get it in php with $thisrequest = $_REQUEST['sk']; you can echo it to see what you get back.